# How to define recursive Property in Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: castle-activerecord, recursion, castle

Suppose you have a class named `MyClass`. `MyClass` should have a property named `Parent`, `Parent` must be of type `MyClass` itself. It is necessary because `MyClass` wants to hold a tree structure.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
public class MyClass {
  [BelongsTo]
  public virtual MyClass Parent { get;set; }
}
```

You might also want to map the collection of children.

See these articles for more information on how to run recursive queries over this:

- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/11/22/ComplexQueriesWithActiveRecord.aspx
- http://web.archive.org/web/20090806071731/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate.aspx
- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/28/nhibernate-tips-amp-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree.aspx

Comment: tnks, your solution worked good. Also this way work too: `[BelongsTo("MyClass")] public virtual MayClass Parent { set; get; ` In this way a column with name `MyClass` is created instead of a column named `Parent`